# Problem with JPA, Id is not registered when trying to save to the database

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jdbc

I'm starting with web development and I'm having problems with jpa. My postegre database when manually entering data into pgAdmin automatically generates an id. But when trying to make a post through curl, for example, an error occurs that says that id cannot be null, that is, the id is no longer generated automatically or, if it is, validation occurs before that. I say this because apparently the other data is correct for registration and I know that my database is working because when I request a get the data appears on the client.I'm using SpringBoot and maven

```
package com.example.umbrellacorporation.model;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name="BOWS")
public class Bows {

  

    

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="AUTHOR")
    private String author;

    @Column(name="BIO_AGENT")
    private String bio_agent;

    @Column(name="ORGANIZATION")
    private String organization;

    @Column(name = "FOUND")
    private String found;

    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "INFOR")
    private String infor;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id" ,columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Integer id;

   

    public Bows() {
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
      }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getBio_agent() {
        return bio_agent;
    }

    public void setBio_agent(String bio_agent) {
        this.bio_agent = bio_agent;
    }

    public String getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(String organization) {
        this.organization = organization;
    }

    public String getFound() {
        return found;
    }

    public void setFound(String found) {
        this.found = found;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getInfor() {
        return infor;
    }

    public void setInfor(String infor) {
        this.infor = infor;
    }



    
}
```

```
package com.example.umbrellacorporation.controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.umbrellacorporation.model.Bows;
import com.example.umbrellacorporation.model.services.BOWSRepositorys;
import java.lang.Iterable;

import java.util.Optional;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

@RestController
public class BowsController {
private final BOWSRepositorys bowsRepositorys;

public BowsController(final BOWSRepositorys bowsRepositorys){
    this.bowsRepositorys = bowsRepositorys;
}



public Iterable<Bows> getAllBows(){
    return this.bowsRepositorys.findAll();
}


@GetMapping("/BOWS/{id}")
public Optional<Bows> getBowsById(@PathVariable Integer id){
    return this.bowsRepositorys.findById(id);
}


@PostMapping("/BOWS")
    public Bows createNewBows(@RequestBody Bows bows) {
           
  return this.bowsRepositorys.save(bows);

    
} }
```

[image]

I have already changed the database and the id properties several times. Which leads me to believe that the problem is in the code.But I have no confidence.I would like jpa to recognize the id automatically generated by the database and not identify a null for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried `GenerationType.IDENTITY`? It is probably the appropriate one, as per [docs](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/persistence/generationtype#IDENTITY): "*the persistence provider must assign primary keys for the entity using a database identity column*". However, be aware that it might not be the most efficient because "*Hibernate cannot use automatic JDBC batching when persisting entities using the IDENTITY generator*" (from [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-identifier-sequence/)).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this generation's strategy

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
```

Try using any of these any of this two:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
```

...or this if the table is created based on the entity...

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "bows_id_sequence", sequenceName = "bows_id_sequence")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "bows_id_sequence")
@Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
```

Also, your JpaReposytory must be correct like:

```
public interface BowsRepository extends JpaRepository<Bows, Integer> {
// your customs queries
}
```